# TikZ/PGFPlots: Avoid scaling for numbers over 99,999 on x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

Using following code the numbers on the x-axis starting to scale for values over 99,999.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar, 
        xmin=0,
        width=10cm,
        height=7cm,
        %enlarge y limits=0.5,
        xlabel={Datensätze},
        %ylabel={Unternehmen},
        symbolic y coords={Commerzbank,Fraport,Gazprom,Tesla,Apple,Microsoft,Berkshire Hathaway,Deutsche Bank},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
        x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        scaled x ticks=false,
        %xtick={0,25000,...,125000},
        xmax=150000,
        xtick align=outside,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates{
            (14587,Deutsche Bank)
            (10464,Berkshire Hathaway)
            (22842,Microsoft)
            (117851,Apple)
            (59088,Tesla)
            (8127,Gazprom)
            (2822,Fraport)
            (2345,Commerzbank)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which generates this output.

[image: Output]

Enabling `xtick={0,25000,...,150000},` will lead to the error `I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.`.

Do you have any thought's on this to prevent the scaling on the x-axis and within the plot? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
  xtick distance=25000,`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve ticks that are typeset as

```
xtick={0,25000,...,150000},
```

you can use

```
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
```

to avoid the `10^...` notation, and

```
xtick distance=25000,
```

to set the distance between subsequent x ticks to be `25000`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar, 
        xmin=0,
        width=10cm,
        height=7cm,
        %enlarge y limits=0.5,
        xlabel={Datens\"atze},
        %ylabel={Unternehmen},
        symbolic y coords={Commerzbank,Fraport,Gazprom,Tesla,Apple,Microsoft,Berkshire Hathaway,Deutsche Bank},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
        x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        scaled x ticks=false,
        xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        xtick distance=25000,
        %xtick={0,25000,...,125000},
        xmax=150000,
        xtick align=outside,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates{
            (14587,Deutsche Bank)
            (10464,Berkshire Hathaway)
            (22842,Microsoft)
            (117851,Apple)
            (59088,Tesla)
            (8127,Gazprom)
            (2822,Fraport)
            (2345,Commerzbank)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to also apply these styles to the `nodes near coords`, you can either use

```
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
```

or just set

```
/pgf/number format/fixed
```

globally in the axis.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar, 
        xmin=0,
        width=10cm,
        height=7cm,
        %enlarge y limits=0.5,
        xlabel={Datens\"atze},
        %ylabel={Unternehmen},
        symbolic y coords={Commerzbank,Fraport,Gazprom,Tesla,Apple,Microsoft,Berkshire Hathaway,Deutsche Bank},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
        x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
        scaled x ticks=false,
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        xtick distance=25000,
        %xtick={0,25000,...,125000},
        xmax=150000,
        xtick align=outside,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates{
            (14587,Deutsche Bank)
            (10464,Berkshire Hathaway)
            (22842,Microsoft)
            (117851,Apple)
            (59088,Tesla)
            (8127,Gazprom)
            (2822,Fraport)
            (2345,Commerzbank)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great. Though, the value behind the bar has still the same issue like before.

Comment: @larkee You can just add `/pgf/number format/fixed` to the options of the axis. I added an explicit version using this.